# Asymptotic Variances of MLE with Orthogonality Constraints

Tags: maximum-likelihood, asymptotics

I have a model that is parameterized by orthogonal matrix $\boldsymbol \Gamma$ and other unconstrained parameters $\theta$ that are closely related to $\boldsymbol \Gamma$ within the model. Restricting to the special orthogonal group, where $|\boldsymbol\Gamma| = 1$, parameters $\boldsymbol\Gamma, \theta$ are identifiable within the model.

Maximum likelihood estimates are achieved by maximizing the log-likelihood $L(\boldsymbol \Gamma, \theta)$. I would like to obtain/study the asymptotic distribution of parameter estimates $\hat{\theta}$, and prove conditions for consistency/asymptotic normality.

Typically, asymptotic variances/distributions for MLE's are obtained through the inverse of the Fisher Information matrix $\boldsymbol I(\boldsymbol\Gamma, \theta)$, which can be interpreted as the curvature of the log-likelihood at the maximum. But I am uncomfortable with applying this directly to my problem, i.e. letting $\boldsymbol I(\boldsymbol\Gamma) = \frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial \boldsymbol vec\boldsymbol\Gamma^2}$ where the entries of $\boldsymbol\Gamma$ are treated as unconstrained real numbers within the derivative, because it seems like I should looking at the curvature along the constrained space $\boldsymbol \Gamma$ lives in.

Is anybody aware of how to tackle this problem? I could not find anything in the literature. One idea I had was to reparametrize $\boldsymbol\Gamma$ with a Cayley transform

$$\boldsymbol\Gamma = (\boldsymbol I - \boldsymbol A)^{-1}(\boldsymbol I + \boldsymbol A) $$

where $\boldsymbol A$ is skew-symmetric, and therefore fully defined by the unconstrained lower triangular entries. But this is going to result in some scary looking second derivatives, so if there is a better way I would be happy to hear it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am a little confused why you are wary of the Fisher information approach. I think that regardless you will need to look at second derivatives if you are after asymptotic normality.

Comment: @Ariel I am not wary of the Fisher Information approach as a whole; I believe, like you say, it is the only way to get at the asymptotic distribution. I am wary of taking derivatives with respect to constrained parameters as if they were unconstrained and carrying on as usual. I could reparametrize with the Cayley Transform, but then my second derivatives will be far messier and subsequent study of the information matrix more difficult. If there is another way to approach this, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: Thanks, I think this clear up my confusion about the question.

Comment: Check this paper for deriving the cramer-rao lower bound under constraints: On the Cramer–Rao Bound Under Parametric Constraints. I am also wondering about proving consistency/asymptotic normality under orthogonality constriant, do you have any ideas?